# React Navigation - How to passing data repeatedly between screens?

Tags: react-native

I'm totally new to react native and this part puzzled me. Sorry if this question kinda basic but I have difficulty googling about react native stuff.

So I have two pages (screens):

1. The first screen (home) is empty.
2. In the second screen (add screen), there's list of people. You could pick one from the list and it will be added to the first screen.
3. So this is what I did so far, I create a *global* variable to contain all people.

   `global.allPerson = '';`
4. In the first screen I put *getParam* as parameter receiver from second screen if exist then concatted to the global variable.

   `const { navigation } = this.props;
   const personName = navigation.getParam('personName', '');
   global.allPerson += "\n" + personName;`
5. From the second screen I pass a *parameter* to first screen like this

   `<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', { peopleName: 'Eric' })}><Text>Add This Person</Text></TouchableHighlight>`

This works, but every time I click the link to the second screen, apparently `global.allPerson += "\n" + personName;` get triggered again.

So let's say I pick "Eric" and then "Michael", It becomes "Eric Eric Michael".

I also tried using state but it's not persistent, it'll only show the last picked one.

At this point I'm not sure what the correct way to create something like this, anybody can show me the right way? Thanks!

Comment: What navigator are you using? Because when you're doing `this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {data})` you're setting up a new instance rather than updating the old state. If you were using stack navigator you could parse the current state in to the next navigator, update, and then re-set the previous state.

Comment: I'm using react navigation v2. I heard it's official navigator solution for react native. Can RN V2 do what you said?

Comment: Sorry, not what I meant! With react-navigation you have different types of Navigators. StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator, SwitchNavigator etc.

Comment: Ah sorry, StackNavigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how I solve this issue using StackNavigator:

**Home Page**

```
<Button onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings', {previousState: this})
}}>
    Some text
</Button>
```

**Settings Page**

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   this.props.navigation.state.params.previousState.setState({
     data: 'Some data I'm passing back to the previous state'
   });
}
```

This doesn't need to be on `componentWillUnmount()` you can trigger this from any function, anytime, anywhere. My use case just happens to be when I unmount (go back) to the previous component which you can do with:

```
this.props.navigation.goBack(null)
```

So you could reset the previous state, before you call goBack.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It works! I concat the current state with new value and put the setState stuff in the onPress instead since I need to trigger goBack at the same time, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: If it's cleaner for you, pass the to a function and just have the button call the function. Glad I could help, as it took me a while to get my head round it too when I first started!